# How to get blog posts by label in blogger api

Tags: java, android, jquery, json, blogger

I using [blogger api](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using) in my android app to integrate blogger content with it by using the REST APIs, as a JSON's objects.

I need to retrieve/filter posts by a label. In most blogs the link of blog's label it usually is

```
https://abtallaldigital.blogspot.com/search/label/Food
https://abtallaldigital.blogspot.com/search/label/Technology
```

I read all API documentation and I see it's deal with Blogs, Posts, Comments, Pages, Users but there's nothing to handle labels/categories in it.

There's a class BloggerAPI in the app that's used to retrieve blogs

```
package abtallaldigital.blogspot.com.dummyapp;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public class BloggerAPI {

    public static final String BASE_URL =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/";
    public static final String KEY = "THE-KEY";

    public static PostService postService = null;

    public static PostService getService() {

        if (postService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
        }

        return postService;
    }

    public interface PostService {
        @GET
        Call<PostList> getPostList(@Url String url);
    }
}
```

It is used thus

```
  private void getData(){

    String url = BloggerAPI.BASE_URL + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.KEY;

    if(token != ""){
        url = url+ "&pageToken="+token;
    }
    if(token == null){
        return;
    }

   final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
            PostList list = response.body();
            token = list.getNextPageToken();
            items.addAll(list.getItems());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error occured",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

I googling for how to get a link of RSS Feed for any label and I found this result

```
https://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/label/?alt=rss
```

this will gets the blog posts of any label with replacing the word "label" in the link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Search query (q=) option**

If you want to get posts with a specific label you could use this query:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/search?q=label:label1&key=THE-KEY

If you want to get posts that are labelled 'this' **as well as** 'that' (if one of them does not match, it's not a match) you could use:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/search?q=label:this+label:that&key=THE-KEY

Use quotes around labels with spaces:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/15045980/posts/search?q=label%3A%22James+Whittaker%22&key=THE-KEY

**Probably a better option to get posts by label**

Source: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list

HTTP-request:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts`

Amongst the optional parameters there is the `labels` parameter:

`labels string  Comma-separated list of labels to search for.`

Example HTTP-request (using the Google Testing Blog's blogId):

GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/15045980/posts?labels=James+Whittaker&key=THE-KEY

Note that quotes around the label should **not** be included using this option.

To fetch the next page of posts store the given `nextPageToken`, as mentioned in the comments, and put it in the `pageToken`-parameter, like:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/15045980/posts?labels=James+Whittaker&pageToken=CgkIChiAjpb65CUQ3KqWBw&key=THE-KEY

Comment: it's working, thank you man :) , Is If I use parameter "nextPageToken": token this will get the second ten items? because I tried it but get the same items

Comment: The "q=" search query delivers a nextPageToken but setting pageToken also yields the same result indeed. GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts?labels=label1&key=THE-KEY&pageToken=nextPageToken-parameter does respect nextPageToken. See https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list

Comment: i know it's not what the OP was asking but if you want to search for 'this' in both labels and content: GET posts/search?q=this|label:this&key=THE-KEY

Comment: @Wieger When I try searching with `labels query param`  I do not get filtered data. I get all the posts https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/xxxxxxx/posts/search?labels=Cucumber&fetchBodies=false&orderBy=updated&status=live&maxResults=10&fetchImages=false` But when I change this  to `q=label:searchValue`  I get the expected filtered data .....https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/xxxxxx/posts/search?q=label:Cucumber&fetchBodies=false&orderBy=updated&status=live&maxResults=10&fetchImages=false